# How to add @ sign as part of object name in JSON via php

Tags: php, json

I need to create JSON with php with this content

```
{
     "@context":"something",
     "type":"something"
}
```

So I created class

```
class doc
{
    public $context;
    public $type;
}
```

which gives me JSON without @ sign

```
{
    "context":"something",
    "type":"something"
}
```

If I add @ in php, I get syntax error. Is it possible that I could use @ as a part of variable name, or how can I do it?

```
class doc
{
    public $@context; //this is a problem
    public $type;
}
```

I need to have object that should be inserted into MongoDB at the end

Comment: Could you show how your json is produced? Do you need your class or could you simpy encode an array to json?

Comment: Why a class? Just populate an associative array with the correct keys and values, and then encode that …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this will do what you want

```
$obj = new stdClass;

$obj->{'@context'} = 'something';
$obj->type = 'somethingelse';

echo json_encode($obj);
```

RESULT

```
{"@context":"something","type":"somethingelse"}
```

Or if you prefer to start with an array

```
$arr = [];
$arr['@context'] = 'something';
$arr['type'] = 'somethingelse';
echo json_encode($arr);
```

RESULT

```
{"@context":"something","type":"somethingelse"}
```

Comment: This first solution you mentioned works if I comment the class that was created in advance. If I don't comment it, it adds @context at the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `associative array` with your `@` in your `keys` and `encode` it to `json`.

```
$array = array(
  '@context'  => 'something',
  'type'      => 'something'
);

print_r( json_encode( $array ) );
```

If you would like to get json out of your class variables, you could use this function:

```
class doc {
  public $context;
  public $type;

  public function getJson() {
    return json_encode( array(
        '@context'  => $this->context,
        'type'      => $this->type,
    ) );
  }
}


$doc = new doc;
$doc->context = 'something';
$doc->type = 'something';

print_r( $doc->getJson() );
```

Both prints

```
{
  "@context":"something",
  "type":"something"
}
```